PineScript - Plot once when condition is met and only plot again when a condition in the opposite direction is met
I would like to plot when a condition, in either direction, is met and then only make the next plot when the condition is met in the opposite direction. My current code plots every time a condition is met regardless of direction. I feel like I should be able to accomplish this with Var and counting but have not been able to work out the logic.
For example (code snippet): plots every time any of the conditions are met (magenta triangles). I only want the first triangle (up or down) not multiple ones in a row.
overBought = input(80)
overSold = input(20)
cross_upper = ta.crossover(rsi, overBought)    //crossing above
cross_lower = ta.crossunder(rsi, overSold)     //crossing below
plotshape(cross_upper, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.bottom, color = #ff00ff, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(cross_lower, style = shape.triangledown, location = location.top, color = #ff00ff, size = size.tiny)
enter image description here
